# Difference between two columns made of sets

Tags: python-polars

Columns 'rule_based' and 'gpt4' are sets of words. How can I create another column named 'diff' which is the difference between the previous two columns?

```
compare_df.with_columns(
    pl.col('rule_based').str.split(';').apply(set),
    pl.col('gpt4').str.split(';').apply(set)
).with_columns(
    diff = pl.col('rule_based') - pl.col('gpt4')
)
```

Code above does not run. It returns:

```
PanicException: `sub` operation not supported for dtype `object`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of working with native Python objects (which is inefficient in general) you can obtain a similar result using polars lists and the method [`polars.Series.list.set_difference`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/series/api/polars.Series.list.set_difference.html):

```
import polars as pl

compare_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {'rule_based': ["def;class;foo;class;set", "list;int;float;list"],
     'gpt4': ["def;class;def;tuple", "import;float"]
     })

compare_df = compare_df.with_columns(
    pl.col('rule_based').str.split(';'),
    pl.col('gpt4').str.split(';')
).with_columns(
    diff=pl.col('rule_based').list.set_difference(pl.col('gpt4'))
)
```

> ```
> ┌───────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
> │ rule_based                ┆ gpt4                        ┆ diff            │
> │ ---                       ┆ ---                         ┆ ---             │
> │ list[str]                 ┆ list[str]                   ┆ list[str]       │
> ╞═══════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════╪═════════════════╡
> │ ["def", "class", … "set"] ┆ ["def", "class", … "tuple"] ┆ ["set", "foo"]  │
> │ ["list", "int", … "list"] ┆ ["import", "float"]         ┆ ["list", "int"] │
> └───────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
> ```

If you want the `rule_based` and `gpt4` columns to have unique values you can also apply `polars.Expr.list.unique`:

```
compare_df.with_columns(
    pl.col('rule_based').str.split(';').list.unique(),
    pl.col('gpt4').str.split(';').list.unique()
).with_columns(
    diff=pl.col('rule_based').list.set_difference(pl.col('gpt4'))
)
```

> ```
> ┌───────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
> │ rule_based                ┆ gpt4                      ┆ diff            │
> │ ---                       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---             │
> │ list[str]                 ┆ list[str]                 ┆ list[str]       │
> ╞═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╪═════════════════╡
> │ ["def", "class", … "set"] ┆ ["def", "class", "tuple"] ┆ ["set", "foo"]  │
> │ ["list", "float", "int"]  ┆ ["import", "float"]       ┆ ["list", "int"] │
> └───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
> ```